# PhpStorm object reference error object within object

Tags: php, object, phpstorm

I have this code, which works fine

```
use path\to\class\exampleClass;
class foo {
  public function preparePortalService() {
    $this->portalService = new exampleClass(array(), $this->getWsdl('portal'));
    $portalservice_header = new \SoapHeader($this->getWsdl('portal'), 'SessionHeader', $header);
    // Set the Session Header.
    $this->portalService->__setSoapHeaders($portalservice_header);
  }
}
```

in another file (which is being autoloaded successfully

```
namespace path\to\class\exampleClass;

class exampleClass extends \SoapClient {
  public function __construct(array $options = array(), $wsdl = 'wsdl/Interface.xml')
  {}
}
```

However, I get a 'Field portalService not found in class foo' warning in PhpStorm (Note: not in the error logs, the code works fine).

Why is this, and how can I get it to recognise the object properties and methods?

**EDIT:** expanded, sorry for the formatting.

To clarify, the class methods and properties autocompletes are accessible through `$portalService` in PhpStorm if I do this:

```
$portalService = new exampleClass(array(), $this->getWsdl('portal'));
```

But if I do this,

```
$this->portalService = $portalService;
```

then PhpStorm tells me it can't find it when I try this

```
$this->portalService->__setSoapHeaders($portalservice_header);
```

Comment: Show us more. Where and how is the class property `postalService` declared? Are you trying to set it without first declaring it?

Comment: Updated. Sorry about the formatting, I'll try and sort that now

Comment: Thanks. that gave me enough info to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStorm is nagging you because although your code will compile and run, it's not well designed.  When you try to assign a new value to `$this->portalService`, the IDE looks around but cannot find any declaration for class property `postalService`.  In short, you are assigning a value to a property that does not exist.

The code still runs because PHP, unlike some other languages, will infer that you *intended* to declare a class property and assign a value to it, even though you never actually declared it.  The better design is to add a declaration:

```
class foo {
  private $postalService=null; //now you've formally declared the class property

  public function preparePortalService() {
    $this->portalService = ... // no problem. this property exists.
  }
}
```

You also mentioned that:

> $portalService = new exampleClass... doesn't pose a problem

That's correct. On this line, you're not referring to a class property (eg: `$this->postalService`, but you are creating and setting a local variable.